# Making menu vertically centred with logo image

Tags: html, css

I'm stuck trying to align the logo in the same height with my menu.
Here the html code:

```css
/*
====================== MAIN ======================

*/
.main-menu {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 16px 5px;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
 width: 100%;
}
.main-menu:before,
.main-menu ul,
.main-menu li,
.main-menu a {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: none;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.main-menu a {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.main-menu,
.main-menu a,
.main-menu a:visited {
  color: #555555;
}
.main-menu > li {
  display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
  float: left;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.main-menu > li > a {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0 10px;
  line-height: 39px;
}
.main-menu > li:hover {
  background-color: #8B008B;
}
.main-menu > li:hover > a,
.main-menu > li:hover > a:visited {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.main-menu li {
  position: relative;
  cursor: default;
}
.main-menu li > a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
.main-menu li > ul{
  z-index: 1;
}

.main-menu .fa {
  font-size: 12pt;
  letter-spacing: 8px;
  line-height: inherit;
}

.main-menu:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
/*

====================== LOGO ======================

*/
.main-menu > li.mm-logo {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.main-menu > li.mm-logo a {
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 0;
}
.main-menu > li.mm-logo img {
border: none;
display: block;
padding:0px;
height: 118px;
width: 118px;
}
.main-menu > li.mm-logo:hover {
background: none;
}
/*


====================== RESPONSIVE ======================

*/
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  /* ====================== MAIN ====================== */
  .main-menu[class*='mm-response'] > li {
    position: relative;
  }
  .main-menu[class*='mm-response'] > li > ul{
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: auto !important;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  .main-menu[class*='mm-response'] > li > ul ul {
    top: 100%;
    margin-left: 39px !important;
  }

  /* ====================== SWITCH ====================== */
  .main-menu.mm-response-switch > li {
    display: none;
    float: none;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .main-menu.mm-response-switch > li + li {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
  .main-menu.mm-response-switch > li.mm-logo {
    display: block;
  }
  .main-menu.mm-response-switch > li.mm-logo img {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  .main-menu.mm-response-switch:before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: '\f0c9';
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    cursor: pointer;
    line-height: 39px;
    height: 39px;
    padding: 0 14px;
    z-index: 2;
  }
  .main-menu.mm-response-switch:hover:before {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .main-menu.mm-response-switch:hover > li {
    display: block;
  }

  /* ====================== RESPONSE MARGIN ====================== */
  .main-menu.mm-response-margin > li > ul {
    margin-left: 39px !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav>
<ul onClick="" class="main-menu mm-response-switch">
        <li class="mm-logo">
                    <a href="index.php"><img src="logo.png" alt="Accueil"></a>
                </li>
        <li>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-indent"></i>Lien 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-indent"></i>Lien 2</a>
        </li>
                <li>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-indent"></i>Lien 2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Don't give more importance to the responsive section, just guide me how to make all elements in the same line vertically.

Comment: Hi, did you get a resolution to your problem? You should accept an answer if you feel the problem is resolved. You can accept an answer with the little checkmark beside answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the floats from the `li` elements and they will align vertically since the `li`'s are `inline-block` and you have already assigned `vertical-align: middle`

```css
/*
====================== MAIN ======================

*/
.main-menu {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 16px 5px;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
 width: 100%;
}
.main-menu:before,
.main-menu ul,
.main-menu li,
.main-menu a {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: none;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.main-menu a {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.main-menu,
.main-menu a,
.main-menu a:visited {
  color: #555555;
}
.main-menu > li {
  display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.main-menu > li > a {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0 10px;
  line-height: 39px;
}
.main-menu > li:hover {
  background-color: #8B008B;
}
.main-menu > li:hover > a,
.main-menu > li:hover > a:visited {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.main-menu li {
  position: relative;
  cursor: default;
}
.main-menu li > a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
.main-menu li > ul{
  z-index: 1;
}

.main-menu .fa {
  font-size: 12pt;
  letter-spacing: 8px;
  line-height: inherit;
}

.main-menu:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
/*

====================== LOGO ======================

*/
.main-menu > li.mm-logo {
  margin-left: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.main-menu > li.mm-logo a {
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 0;
}
.main-menu > li.mm-logo img {
border: none;
display: block;
padding:0px;
height: 118px;
width: 118px;
}
.main-menu > li.mm-logo:hover {
background: none;
}
/*


====================== RESPONSIVE ======================

*/
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  /* ====================== MAIN ====================== */
  .main-menu[class*='mm-response'] > li {
    position: relative;
  }
  .main-menu[class*='mm-response'] > li > ul{
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: auto !important;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  .main-menu[class*='mm-response'] > li > ul ul {
    top: 100%;
    margin-left: 39px !important;
  }

  /* ====================== SWITCH ====================== */
  .main-menu.mm-response-switch > li {
    display: none;
    float: none;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .main-menu.mm-response-switch > li + li {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
  .main-menu.mm-response-switch > li.mm-logo {
    display: block;
  }
  .main-menu.mm-response-switch > li.mm-logo img {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  .main-menu.mm-response-switch:before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: '\f0c9';
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    cursor: pointer;
    line-height: 39px;
    height: 39px;
    padding: 0 14px;
    z-index: 2;
  }
  .main-menu.mm-response-switch:hover:before {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .main-menu.mm-response-switch:hover > li {
    display: block;
  }

  /* ====================== RESPONSE MARGIN ====================== */
  .main-menu.mm-response-margin > li > ul {
    margin-left: 39px !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav>
<ul onClick="" class="main-menu mm-response-switch">
        <li class="mm-logo">
                    <a href="index.php"><img src="logo.png" alt="Accueil"></a>
                </li>
        <li>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-indent"></i>Lien 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-indent"></i>Lien 2</a>
        </li>
                <li>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-indent"></i>Lien 2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

You can also use flexbox and assign `display: flex; align-items: center;` to the parent `ul`

```css
/*
====================== MAIN ======================

*/
.main-menu {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 16px 5px;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
 width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.main-menu:before,
.main-menu ul,
.main-menu li,
.main-menu a {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: none;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.main-menu a {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.main-menu,
.main-menu a,
.main-menu a:visited {
  color: #555555;
}
.main-menu > li {
  display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.main-menu > li > a {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0 10px;
  line-height: 39px;
}
.main-menu > li:hover {
  background-color: #8B008B;
}
.main-menu > li:hover > a,
.main-menu > li:hover > a:visited {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.main-menu li {
  position: relative;
  cursor: default;
}
.main-menu li > a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
.main-menu li > ul{
  z-index: 1;
}

.main-menu .fa {
  font-size: 12pt;
  letter-spacing: 8px;
  line-height: inherit;
}

.main-menu:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
/*

====================== LOGO ======================

*/
.main-menu > li.mm-logo {
  margin-left: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.main-menu > li.mm-logo a {
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 0;
}
.main-menu > li.mm-logo img {
border: none;
display: block;
padding:0px;
height: 118px;
width: 118px;
}
.main-menu > li.mm-logo:hover {
background: none;
}
/*


====================== RESPONSIVE ======================

*/
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  /* ====================== MAIN ====================== */
  .main-menu[class*='mm-response'] > li {
    position: relative;
  }
  .main-menu[class*='mm-response'] > li > ul{
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: auto !important;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  .main-menu[class*='mm-response'] > li > ul ul {
    top: 100%;
    margin-left: 39px !important;
  }

  /* ====================== SWITCH ====================== */
  .main-menu.mm-response-switch > li {
    display: none;
    float: none;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .main-menu.mm-response-switch > li + li {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
  .main-menu.mm-response-switch > li.mm-logo {
    display: block;
  }
  .main-menu.mm-response-switch > li.mm-logo img {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  .main-menu.mm-response-switch:before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: '\f0c9';
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    cursor: pointer;
    line-height: 39px;
    height: 39px;
    padding: 0 14px;
    z-index: 2;
  }
  .main-menu.mm-response-switch:hover:before {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .main-menu.mm-response-switch:hover > li {
    display: block;
  }

  /* ====================== RESPONSE MARGIN ====================== */
  .main-menu.mm-response-margin > li > ul {
    margin-left: 39px !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul onClick="" class="main-menu mm-response-switch">
    <li class="mm-logo">
      <a href="index.php"><img src="logo.png" alt="Accueil"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-indent"></i>Lien 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-indent"></i>Lien 2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-indent"></i>Lien 2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Ohh man, yeah it really worked for me thanks a lot a lot, just another question,  i have a link that it is supposed to be in the right position of the menu, i gave him the class "mm-right-item" with that css code: .main-menu > li.mm-right-item { margin-right: 0; float: right; } it goes to the right with your first solution but not in the middle, i guess the float thing don't work in that case.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this;

One technique is to give the parent position: relative, then absolutely position the logo `top: 50%` then `transformY(-50%)` which translates in english to "Position the top of the logo in the parent 1/2 way down, then move the logo up 1/2 of its height.

There is a handy flow chart for different techniques to use here. 
https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.main-menu{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

And revert it to display:block when the screen is too small:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px)
.main-menu{
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

If you want more info about flexbox, I suggest you this great article: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: i tried this solution, it worked but all others elements got missed up in responsive mode.

Comment: i edited my answer so your responsive layout should still be working

Comment: Yeahh of course, sometimes i am so stupid. Man you saved my life thanks you a lot, you are a genius.
Just another question, i have a link that it is supposed to be in the right position of the menu, i gave him the class "mm-right-item"  with that css code:
.main-menu > li.mm-right-item {
margin-right: 0;
  float: right;
}

but it dosen't go to the right.

Comment: To place the elements relative to the others, you can use the `order` property. `.main-menu li{ order: 1 }  li.mm-right { order: 2 } `. If you do that, in order to keep it responsive, replace the `display:block` by `flex-direction:column` ( see my last edit )
If you want your element to the right of the screen, add a filler div like `<div class="filler"></div>  .filler{ flex-grow: 1 }` before the li you want to push to the right

Comment: It was my first post here in stackoverflow, for real you are a great community, thanks a lot for your help. I tried your last solution and it fixed every thing, thank you again for your time.